# ¿Cómo animar un texto en Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

En mi app android, quisiera que al abrirla aparezca una tira de texto pasando horizontalmente de derecha a izquierda de la pantalla. Cuando finalice la transmisión, vuelva a empezar.
Siendo el texto de mi TextView: "Hola. Bienvenido!"

Comment: Hola Tony, saludos, Has relizado o investigado algo sobre esto? ver [ask].

Comment: Sí, he investigado. Pero no he encontrado nada que me ayude. Creando páginas webs sé cómo animar un texto (con JavaScript), pero en android no tengo ni idea.  SALUDOS!

Comment: Se a lo que te refieres Tony , es un "marquee" similar a lo que se realiza en web, pero  trata de agregar información y se más especifico, te aseguro que de esta forma tu pregunta será más interesante y obtendrías mejores respuestas. Si modificas tu pregunta agregando información o imagen de lo que deseas yo podría ayudarte así como otros desarrolladores.

Comment: una forma es directamente en el layout, así que agrega tu xml para una buena respuesta

Comment: No he modificado el TextView en mi xml. Sólo el texto. Gracias por los consejos.

Answer (score 0):

No creo que esta respuesta sea la correcta pero he hecho este bucle que recrea una especie de "marquee":

```
        TextView tvHelloWorld = findViewById(R.id.tv_helloworld);

        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        int screenWidth = size.x;

        animateTranslationLeftToRight(tvHelloWorld , screenWidth);

//...

    public void animateTranslationLeftToRight(View view, int screenSize){
        int duration = 3000;
        int translationLeftX = screenSize * -1;
        int translationRightX = screenSize;

        view.setTranslationX(translationLeftX); // lo mueves a la izquierda
        view.animate().translationXBy(translationLeftX).translationX(translationRightX)
                .setDuration(duration)
                .withEndAction(()-> animateTranslationLeftToRight(view)); // lo mueves de izquierda a derecha
    }
```

Lo que debes tener en cuenta es que el `translationLeftX` y `translationRightX` debe ser el ancho de la pantalla y también deberás calcular la duración dependiendo de este factor ya que no es lo mismo la duración que debe tener en una tablet que un dispositivo más pequeño.

**Resultado**:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero que te sirva.
Saludos.

Comment: No se ve exactamente como me gustaria. Es como si el texto diera saltitos. Debería desplazarse con más suavidad. Pero de momento me sirve. Hasta que aprenda una forma más adecuada. Gracias...

Comment: Jugando con la duración puedes hacer que se desplace más suave. Que bueno que te sirva. Saludos.

Comment: Hola Fabio! No pude conectarme antes. Sigo teniendo un problema.  En la última linea del código:  ...animateTranslationLeftToRight(view));  me subraya 'view'  diciendo que no se puede aplicar en mi MainActivity. He comprobado que tengo todo lo de más igual que tu código. Cuál podría ser la causa??? Gracias..